# Viewing a single mail file in a maildir

Tags: major-mode, email

Is there any major mode that allows one to properly view a single mail file in a maildir?

By "properly" here I mean similar to "big" email clients, like mu4e or gnus, so allowing (at least) view headers and text parts of an email, hiding unencoded parts (images, files).

Comment: Define "properly". Say what the problem is. Question needs clarification.